# MySQL - Delete dependent foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys I have table A and B like below. When I setup the tables and foreign keys I DID NOT do the option if the foreign key is removed delete the item (and I dont want that because there are other spots that is is needed) but I am trying to write a single sql query that will remove all references of uid 1 in table A, B and whatever else it might be linked in (in reality I have 9 references for the Items I need to delete)

Any Ideas?

```
Table A
uid          Data
1              1
2              3
3              9

Table B
uid           TableA_uid_fk
7                 1
10                3
13                2
```

Comment: PS This is MySQL (sorry for not mentioning that)

Comment: It's indicated by the tags, which is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete with join. Have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847183/php-delete-links-rows-from-mysql-databse/9847308#9847308) too :

```
delete tablea, tableb from tablea,tableb where tablea.uid = <whatever> and tablea.uid=tableb.tablea_uid_fk;
```